# Why do the filters now filter out questions with answers?

Tags: support, filtering, tag-filters

Maybe it’s just me, but a few days ago I started wondering why the Stack Overflow actitivity had fallen down considerably. Now it seems that all my filters cause only questions with 0 answers to be shown. I haven’t changed the filters for a long time, and I don’t even see any setting for filtering out questions based on the number of answers posted (which would be a useful feature as such).

Update: My main filter is https://stackexchange.com/filters/33484/html-and-others and it works fine now that I test it on Chrome (or on IE). I have used StackExchange almost exclusively on Firefox. So this seems to be a browser problem with Firefox (I’m using version 34.0 on Win 7; I think I upgraded to 34.0 about the same time as the problem emerged).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only possible cause of this problem I can imagine is that you selected "no answers" instead of "newest". Select "newest" then.

> [image]

Comment: Oh my... blush... yes, that was the reason. I can’t recollect having selected “no answers”, but I must have done that somehow by accident. Thanks.